# Drupal and Login Toboggan -- infinite redirect loop

Tags: php, drupal, redirect, module, loops

I'm getting a redirect loop when using Login Toboggan. It doesn't happen all of the time and I think I've narrowed it down to something with the session, specifically the active-tabs[last-active-href] value.

Since it's intermittent, I was able to print out a session of a working copy and a non-working copy. Here are both:

WORKS -- Array ( [active-tabs] => Array ( [last-active-href] => index ) ) toboggan/denied

DOESN'T WORK -- Array ( [active-tabs] => Array ( [last-active-href] => user/register [user] => user/register ) [wantsEvents] => [wantsResources] => [wantsSupport] => ) toboggan/denied

I've also noticed that if I comment out the following line the redirection loop stops (although no page loads):

$return = menu_execute_active_handler('user/register');

Any ideas? I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Hi there, did you disallow user registration?
Also, you might want to post this information at the [Issue Queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/logintoboggan?categories=All) on Drupal, in the case you can't get a good answer here. [Here's the Create Issue page](http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/logintoboggan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved here: http://drupal.org/node/802330#comment-2987308

Was an issue combining Login Toboggan and Smart Tabs.

@sirhc thanks for pointing me to the Drupal Issue page.